# Loop through column names in Fixed Effects Regression

Tags: r, plm

I am trying to code a fixed effects regression, but I have MANY dummy variables. Basically, I have 184 variables on the RHS of my equation. Instead of writing this out, I am trying to create a loop that will pass through each column (I have named each column with a number).

This is the code i have so far, but the paste is not working. I may be totally off base using paste, but I wasn't sure how else to approach this. However, I am getting an error (see below).

```
FE.model <- plm(avg.kw ~ 0 + (for (i in 41:87) {
                    paste("hour.dummy",i,sep="") + paste("dummy.CDH",i,sep="")
                   + paste("dummy.MA",i,sep="") + paste("DR.variable",i,sep="")
              }),
              data = data.reg,
              index=c('Site.ID','date.hour'),
              model='within',
              effect='individual') 
summary(FE.model)
```

As an example for the column names, when i=41 the names should be "hour.dummy41" "dummy.CDH41", etc.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in paste("hour.dummy", i, sep = "") + paste("dummy.CDH", i, sep = "") : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

So I'm not sure if it's the paste function that is not appropriate here, or if it's the loop. I can't seem to find a way to loop through column names easily in R.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where do these indicator variables come from? I think the usual idiom is to use `factor`, so something like `y ~ x1 + x2 + factor(hour)`, where `hour` is the hour of day, rather than generating 24 indicator variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring worries about fitting a model with so many terms for the moment, you probably want to generate a string, and then cast it as a formula:

```
#create a data.frame where rows are the parts of the variable names, then collapse it
rhs <- do.call(paste, c(as.list(expand.grid(c("hour.dummy","dummy.CDH"), 41:87)), sep=".", collapse=" + "))
fml <- as.formula(sprintf ("avg.kw ~ %s"), rhs))
FE.model <-pml(flm, ...
```

I've only put in two of the 'dummy's in the second line- but you should get the idea

Comment: That worked!!! Yes, a lot of terms but this is how we do modelling for this type of analysis. Thanks so much!

Comment: Gavin - for the rhs you created - how would I add another dummy to that but instead of 41:87, it was 1:24?

Comment: `...as.list(rbind(expand.grid(vars1, 41:87), expand.grid(vars2, 1:24)) ...`

Comment: Fantastic! Much appreciated!